# Ubuntu 20.04 installation problems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (alongside windows and/or otherwise) (specifications are given below) but I couldn't.

- I have tried clean installing windows and then installing Ubuntu 20.04.
- I have deleted windows and only installed ubuntu.
- I have installed 19.10 and then tried to update it to ubuntu 20.04. All of the above did not work.

I have made bootable USB using Rufus (tried MBR and GPT both). Windows 10 installation is no problem. But I need Ubuntu for work purposes. Also, not that when this loading screen appears, it stays that way for hours and when I try to hard shut down and then start again, the same screen appears, not the setup menu which is weird. My bios settings are set to `UEFI + Legacy`.

Also, I tried 18.04 LTS and that doesn't work either and neither does 20.04 LTS. 19.10 was working fine with a few minor glitches but that's not a long-term solution right?

Computer specifications:

| Part | Specs |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | 19 9980xe |
| MoBo | MSI creator x299 |
| GPU | 2xRTX2080Ti |
| Ram | 128 Gskill |
| SSD | 2TB 970 Samsung |

Comment: Just check if updating the Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) to any latest version if provided by MSI can help. In case any options like Fast Boot are Enabled in Firmware setup, try disabling them.However option like Fast Boot might be dependent on OS selection option. Some may have an option to select Windows 10 / Other OS or something like Windows 10 WHQL Support etc. If so try disabling it.

Comment: here are the bios settings - https://imgur.com/a/bQfMau4

I just can't seem to boot from the USB installer for ubuntu

Comment: Try disabling Windows 10 WHQL or Enabling Windows 7 Installation option and see if that makes any difference. If you can not boot from USB or if it does not stop at Boot Menu, then also try resetting the CMOS.

Comment: Have you checked for a second key to change boot order, as opposed to doin it in BIOS/UEFI? On one PC, I found that F2, for example, goes to BIOS where boot order can be set, *but that setting is ignored*, and F9 must be pressed during boot to select the boot device.

Answer (score 2):

After clicking "START" in Rufus, choose "Write in DD Image Mode" (it will prompt you).

A live Linux image doesn't always want to boot from a USB if it is written in ISO Image Mode, at least in my experience.